# Envia dados via post

Tags: laravel, post, token, postman

Tenho o seguinte método

```
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use Validator;
    use App\Pessoa;
    class PessoaController extends Controller
   {

    public function lista( Request $request ){
            $nome     = "%".$request->input( 'nome' )."%";
            $telefone = "%".$request->input( 'telefone' )."%";
            $empresa  = $request->input( 'empresa' );
            $setor    = $request->input( 'setor' );
            $cargo    = $request->input( 'cargo' );
            $email    = "%".$request->input( 'email' )."%";
            $pessoa = Pessoa::with(['empresa', 'setor','cargo'])
                             ->where( [
                                         [ 'nm_pessoa', 'like', $nome],
                                         [ 'telefone', 'like', $telefone ],
                                         [ 'email', 'like', $email ],
                                         [ 'cd_empresa', 'like', $empresa ],
                                         [ 'cd_setor', 'like', $setor ],
                                         [ 'cd_cargo', 'like', $cargo ]
                                    ] )
                             ->get();
            return response()->json( $pessoa );

        }
}
```

Tenho as seguinte rota

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api'], function(){
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'pessoa'], function (){
         Route::get( '', 'PessoaController@lista' );
         Route::post( 'add', ['as' => 'add', 'uses' => 'PessoaController@add'] );
    });
});
```

Gostaria de enviar dados via post, mas só que dá essa mensagem aqui:

> Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \
>
> MethodNotAllowedHttpException
>
> No message

E via get funciona

No arquivo VerifyCsrfToken.php

Eu deixei assim

```
protected $except = [
        'api/pessoa/*'
    ];
}
```

E no Kernel.php

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
         //   \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
         //   \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
          //  \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        //    \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        //    \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
```

Que é para não chegar o token porque não consegui enviar do cliente fora do laravel

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O problema é a barra na frente do link, remova para testar e avisa. `http://localhost/controle/api/pessoa`

Comment: Que barra? Não entendi

Comment: Na chamada do POST, no Postman. Você colocou uma barra no final do link. Remove ela.

Comment: Isso mesmo. Deu certo. Muito obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É necessário remover a barra nas chamadas POST.

Se houver uma barra no final, a requisição se converte magicamente para GET.

`http://localhost/controle/api/pessoa`

Confesso que não tenho certeza se a alteração disso é no cliente ou no servidor, mas acredito que seja do servidor pois já vi regras de .htaccess para tratar isso.

[Este conteúdo](http://blog.caelum.com.br/rest-principios-e-boas-praticas/) pode ajudar com algumas coisas adicionais para manter sua API legal.

Comment: Cara muito obrigado mesmo